# Ramda compare two arrays of objects based on one property

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Test 1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      name: "Test 2"
    }
]

arr2 = [
    {
      groupId: "125",
      age: 44,
      subGroup: {
        id: "1",
        name: "Test 1"
      }
    }
]
```

Using Ramda, I need to compare arr1 and arr2, and return matching object from arr2 based on id (id: "1")

So the result should be:

```
[
    {
      groupId: "125",
      age: 44,
      subGroup: {
        id: "1",
        name: "Test 1"
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: You can solve it using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`R.innerJoin()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#innerJoin) to intersect between two arrays (`arr2` & `arr1`), and get items from the 1st array (`arr2` in your case):

```js
const fn = R.innerJoin((a, b) => a.subGroup?.id === b.id)

const arr1 = [{"id":"1","name":"Test 1"},{"id":"2","name":"Test 2"}]
const arr2 = [{"groupId":"125","age":44,"subGroup":{"id":"1","name":"Test 1"}},{"groupId":"126","age":46}]

const result = fn(arr2, arr1)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```